# hibernate fechting old data using glassfish pool

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session, glassfish

I am facing an issue with hibernate hibernate-core-3.5.4-Final, using a JDBC pool through Glassfish 3.

But when I am running a query over it, old data is fetched from the DB.
Here is the method:

```
 String queryString = "FROM EntityObject WHERE name = :name  order by startDate desc";

 Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
 query.setParameter("name", "Smith");
 query.setMaxResults(1);
 EntityObject entityObject = (EntityObject) query.uniqueResult();
```

hibernate configuration:

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class" >thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/ClusterDatasource</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

        <mapping ...  />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the Glassfish pool with default values.

I create the Session in the constructor of the class as follow:

```
 sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(CONFIG_FILE).buildSessionFactory();
 session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
 session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
```

I do not know if it is a cache issue with hibernate and/or glassfish or other reason?

Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks

Comment: It could be settings of the Transaction isolation. So, do, you query this in the same transaction or different transaction? If you saved something in between these two queries, try to check the DB if the values is saved or not, if it is not saved, then do session.flush() when you save into the DB.

Comment: Remove this and try, session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);

Comment: I tried with the 4 isolation level and It did not work. In addition to that, the saves are performed from another system, so I do not think that is a flush problem.

Comment: If a open a session each time that I do the query it works, but i do not know the performance impact.

Comment: You can try with the stateless session then http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession

Comment: No luck with stateless session:
collections cannot be fetched by a stateless session

Comment: You mentioned "If a open a session each time that I do the query it works, but i do not know the performance impact." in one of your earlier comment, That is the solution, I've overlooked this comment. Opening a transaction every time does not have any performance hit. Try using requires_new transaction propagation on the service where the data is retrieved.